# Changing Watchface in android Wear from companion app?

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api, watchface

We can change watchface of wear watch from google official wear app. How can I implement same functionality in my companion app? What should be the approach?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, if the user installs an app that contains a wearable app with watch face, it becomes available on the Android Wear companion app

> Android Wear enables you to create custom watch faces for Wear devices. When users install a handheld app that contains a wearable app with watch faces, they become available in the Android Wear companion app on the handheld device and in the watch face picker on the wearable device.

Which is on the overview of the [Watch Face documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html). So I believe you don't need to do anything as long as the handheld app has a wearable app with watch face.

Comment: I know it is possible to change watchface from watch face selector in android wear. But my question is how I can change watchface through companion app like it is possible in Android wear official app???